# How to navigate to a nib(view) when a cell is pressed on a UITableView(on another nib/view)?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I want the functionality similar to the last tabs in a tab bar (those that are shown in a table after pressing the "..."  )

Each points to another view.

My table

page a>

page b>

page c>

I guess that the code should be in didSelectRowAtIndexPath
but

1. I dont know how to call a nib based on the table
2. I dont know if after navigating to the next nib ... I'll be able to navigate back

Thanks
Asaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy&paste from random project:

```
-(void)navigateToFAQ
{
    UIViewController *faqBrowser = [[UIViewController alloc] autorelease];
    [faqBrowser initWithNibName:@"faqBrowser" bundle:nil];

    // EDIT: sorry, leave this out this is my own category to UIBarButtonItem!
    //faqBrowser.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem arrowLeftWithText:@"back" target:self action:@selector(dismiss)];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:faqBrowser animated:YES];
    faqBrowser.title = @"FAQ";
}

-(void)dismiss
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

call `[self navigateToFaq]` from your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

and make sure you have a nib file called faqBrowser.xib...

Comment: I'm trying to implement this in a modal view... can this be the reason it doesn't work?
(I guess it is I hope it isn't)

Comment: howcome? this is actually a faq browser from a "..." more menu like you were asking about.

Comment: OK, I don't know what I've done wrong yesterday... but now it works.

But I do have an issue:
Calling from the table to the nib works...
going back from the nib to the table works...
calling the nib again ... crashes

It's like I'm trying to build an already existing object
(I know that because if I go back to the level before the table, it works)

Any ideas?

Thanks
Asaf

Comment: the comments section is not the place for new questions, and as allways, elaborate on the crash: what does the console show etc. The going back-forth kind of crash typically indicates bad memory handling; balance your allocs and releases, NSLog you didReceiveMemoryWarnings to see if that correlates to crashes. And if you think the current question is answered, accept the answer.